# ARC and ViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have a little misunderstanding regarding ARC. I'm creating a new UIViewController using the following code:

```
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    LocationProfileView *locationProfile = [[LocationProfileView alloc] initWithLocation:l];

    locationProfile.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenRect.size.height, screenRect.size.width, 400);
    [appDelegate.window addSubview:locationProfile.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
      locationProfile.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height);
    }];
```

In its UIVIew I put a button which removes the view from screen. The problem with this is that `locationProfile` gets deallocated immediately after its being added to screen, so everytime I'm trying to tap on "Close" button (which calls a method in `LocationProfileView` class) my application will crash.

So I added a property:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) LocationProfileView *locationProfile;
```

and changed the second line of code in:

```
locationProfile = [[LocationProfileView alloc] initWithLocation:l];
```

but now my class won't be deallocated until I initiate it again (because it loses the reference to the first instance of `LocationProfileView`?). What should I do to make my class being deallocated every time I tap on "Close" button? I guess that setting `locationProfile` to `nil` would work, but this means that I'll have to call a method in the main class (the one which contains the code block).

What is the proper way for doing this? Sorry if my questions is too noobish.

Note:
`l` is an instance of a custom class which contains some infos to be displayed in `LocationProfileView`'s `UIVIew`.

Comment: Where is the `UIViewController` that you mention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)closeButtonCallBack {
    [self.locationProfile removeFromSuperview];
    self.locationProfile = nil;
}
```

i am assuming the target of your close button is the viewcontroller itself

a strong pointer will the retain the object until the viewController itself is deallocated, unless you assign to it nil

a local variable will be deallocated when it goes out of scope

ALTERNATIVELY

without using the strong pointer, you can do this

```
LocationProfileView *locationProfile = [[LocationProfileView alloc] initWithLocation:l];

UIButton *close = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
close.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 30);
[close addTarget:locationProfile action:@selector(removeFromSuperview) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:close];
```

Answer (score 1):

In your original example,

```
LocationProfile *locationProfile=...
```

is a local variable. So it's released as soon as you return from the constructor. That's what you observed.

When you make it a strong property, the view controller retains the locationProfile:

```
 @property(nonatomic, strong) LocationProfileView *locationProfile;
```

Comment: It's not necessarily being released after the constructor, but definitely when the function's stack frame gets crushed.

Comment: Sorry but this is just wrong. You don't need to explicitly release a retained property under ARC, and setting a local ivar to nil does not release it anyway.

Comment: @ChrisH "local ivar" doesn't make sense; what were you trying to say?

Comment: Sorry that's a typo. Should have said "...setting an ivar..." What was trying to say is that when you are using synthesized properties with ARC you don't need to do anything in dealloc to release them yourself. Also setting an ivar to nil doesn't release the originally allocated object it was pointing to.

Comment: @ChrisH: you're right, I'm wrong. Deleted misleading material in the answer.